# consuming custom event of one user control in another user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

In UserControl1 there is a custom event which I want to wire in UserControl2.

in UserControl1 I have declared the custom event as:

```
 public event MYDelegate SendMessage;
```

while my delegate defination is in other class library as:

```
public delegate string MYDelegate(string message);
```

I am firing SendMessage in my code as below:

```
  SendMessage(txt.Text);
```

Kindly guide me how to wire SendMessage() event in UserControl2. My idea was do something like in below example but not sure how to get/ access UserControl1 object in UserControl2.

Please help me.

```
UserControl1.SendMessge+=ListnerMetod();
```

Comment: Are both usercontrols hosted by the same parent?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use [MessageBus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722675/implementing-a-message-bus-architecture) so it will look like this: http://www.ronaldwidha.net/2010/05/31/a-simple-example-of-the-webformsmvp-cross-presenter-messaging/

Answer (score 4):

You are almost there. You just need to attach SendMessage to UserControl2's ListnerMetod.

As Mark Hall said, it is not a good practice to fire an event from one control to another without parent page knowing.

Here is the sample code of firing an event through a parent page.

### Default.aspx (Parent Page)

```
<%@ Register Src="SenderUserControl.ascx" TagName="SenderUserControl" 
  TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register Src="ReceiverUserControl.ascx" TagName="ReceiverUserControl" 
  TagPrefix="uc2" %>
<uc1:SenderUserControl ID="SenderUserControl1" runat="server" />
<uc2:ReceiverUserControl ID="ReceiverUserControl1" runat="server" />

public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SenderUserControl1.SendMessage += m => ReceiverUserControl1.ListnerMethod(m);
    }
}
```

### SenderUserControl.ascx

```
public delegate void MessageHandler(string message);

public partial class SenderUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public event MessageHandler SendMessage;

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendMessage("test");
    }
}
```

### ReceiverUserControl.ascx

```
public partial class ReceiverUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public void ListnerMethod(string message)
    {

    }
}
```

### ***Credit to Mark Hall***

Answer (score 2):

If both UserControls are hosted by the same parent, attach a handler in the parent to the UserControls event that you want to subscribe to then call a method in the second UserControl in the handler.

Comment: is there no way I can wire it directly user control to user control ? or directly between a master page to user control or content page to master ?

Comment: Is this Asp.net or Winforms?

Comment: I work mostly in Winforms or Wpf, you can try something like this to see if it will work.  `userControl1.SendMessage += new UserControl1.MyDelegate(userControl2.ListenerMethod);` This is just adding the listener Method as the EventHandler. Make sure the Method has the same return type as the Delegate.

Comment: @user2279051 I just tested on an ASP.Net Project and it works also.

Comment: it looks like I m doing something wrong or missing something. Can you please confirm are you doing from usercontrol to usercontrol ? or from usercontrol to masterpage ? If possible can you please share your code.

Comment: It is not good for an UserControl to have knowledge of another UserControl, I did it in the Page_Load event of the Page they were hosted on. You will need to use the instance names of the UserControls.

Comment: Thanks @Mark, just last thing to ask you please.

You said it is not good for UC to know other UC. Then what is best way to to UC or component communication ?

Comment: The best way is to have the object that hosts the usercontrols handle the communication using public properties, methods and events.